# How to access uploaded files in frontend in the controller in Typo3?

Tags: php, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

In typo3 i created a domain model for persons with the extension builder. One of the properties should be a profile picture. I need some help on how to pass the uploaded file to my controller.

The form for creating, editing looks something like this:

```
<f:form action="update" arguments="{picture:picture}" name="person" object="{person}" >
  <f:form.upload  name="picture" class="imageupload"  />
  <f:form.textfield property="firstName" />
  <f:form.textfield property="lastName" />
<f:form.submit value="Save" />
```

the update action in the controller:

```
public function updateAction(\Vendor\Persons\Domain\Model\Person $person, $picture) {
    $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    $storage = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getDefaultStorage();
    $file = $storage->getFolder('images')->addFile($picture);

    $fileReference = $objectManager->get(\Vendor\Persons\Domain\Model\FileReference::class);
    $fileReference->setFile($file);

    $person->setPicture($fileReference);

    $this->personRepository->update($person);
}
```

the FileReference Class:

```
class FileReference extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference {

/**
 * uid of a sys_file
 *
 * @var integer
 */
protected $originalFileIdentifier;

/**
 * setOriginalResource
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference $originalResource
 * @return void
 */
public function setOriginalResource(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference $originalResource) {
    $this->originalResource = $originalResource;
    $this->originalFileIdentifier = (int)$originalResource->getOriginalFile()->getUid();
}

/**
 * setFile
 *
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File $falFile
 * @return void
 */
public function setFile(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File $falFile) {
    $this->originalFileIdentifier = (int)$falFile->getUid();
}

}
```

When i just hardcode a path to an image inside the addFile() function in the update action, everything seems to work, the file gets copied to fileadming and a filereference is created. However i have no idea on how to access the uploaded image from the form upload. I'm not even sure if the image is uploaded at all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your form need to set to `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. This allows the form to submit your uploaded files.

Then, you should change your property to `<f:form.upload  property="picture.originalResource" class="imageupload"  />` to assign your file automaticaly to your picture refrence.

If you want to handle the upload by yourself can take an look on following code I used for TYPO3 8.7:

```
# Set target Folder
$mediaFolder = 'path/to/images';
$storage     = $this->storageRepository->findByUid(1);

# check if target folder exist or create it
if ($storage->hasFolder($mediaFolder)) {
  $targetFolder = $storage->getFolder($mediaFolder);
} else {
  $targetFolder = $storage->createFolder($mediaFolder);
}

# add uploaded file
$imageFile = $targetFolder->addUploadedFile($picture, DuplicationBehavior::RENAME);

# FileReference is the instance of your extension
/** @var FileReference $imageFileReference */
$imageFileReference = $this->objectManager->get(FileReference::class);
$imageFileReference->setOriginalResource($imageFile);
$imageFileReference->setPid($person->getPid());

$person->setPicture($imageFileReference);
```

Comment: with `$this->storageRepository->findByUid(1);` you assign the storage `1` statically. You still have a recipe to do it dynamically? Else it's not working if different storage is used.

Comment: You can use `$storage = ResourceFactory::getInstance()->getDefaultStorage();` to get the storage marked as `default`. You can also set the storage PID in your plugin settings so you can change it via typoscript.

Comment: Thank's, that's completing the answer!